# Turning Entitlements on in Xcode Prevents Bare Bones App From Launching

Tags: xcode, mac-app-store, entitlements

I created a basic application in Xcode 4.2.  Very simple application, I have not changed a single thing.  Push run, and you get the standard base application window.  If I turn entitlements on for my target and hit run, I don't get any debugger errors, but the window never comes up.  I checked the logs with Console.app and got the following:

First error I get:

```
taskgated: killed com.alsbury.EntitlementsTest[pid 15903] because its use of the com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers entitlement is not allowed
```

After removing the iCloud Containers "com.alsbury.EntitlementsTest" I get this error:

```
taskgated: killed com.alsbury.EntitlementsTest[pid 15903] because its use of the com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers entitlement is not allowed
```

Because of the iCloud type stuff, I even added an Application to my developer account, a provisioning profile and added my machine.  Any thoughts? Very confused right now.

Comment: You said you have a developer account, are you a registered mac developer(of the paid developer program)?

Comment: Yes, I have a paid desktop developer account.

Comment: David, how are things going with this, are you still having problems?

Comment: I also have this problem. Tried: (1) turning iCloud off for the app id (and regenerating provisioning profiles); (2) using both development and distribution provisioning profiles (the development one had my machine ID registered); (3) entering no iCloud entitlements (in which case Xcode autogenerates them), entering empty iCloud entitlements (empty array, empty string), entering correct iCloud entitlements; (4) disabling sandboxing; (5) leaving sandboxing enabled and deleting the container. Nothing helps. Works after disabling entitlements. Xcode 4.2.1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure of a few things. It's unfortunately a tedious process, but if you follow the steps carefully, you should be all set.

**1)** In the Developer Certificate Utility page on Apple's site, you have your machine registered along with its UUID.

**2)** You've created and downloaded a development certificate.

**3)** Your App ID (in the same utility) is configured for iCloud. This generally just involves you checking a checkbox.

**4)** Your development provisioning profile for your application is pointing to the App ID mentioned in **(3)**, and also the hardware system registered in **(1)**, and also the certificate mentioned in **(2)**

**5)** After downloading the new provisioning profile, install it both in the system by double-clicking it, and in Xcode by dragging it to the "Provisioning Profiles" pane in your Organizer.

**6)** In the Build Settings for your application, make sure that the Code Signing Identity is pointing to your new provisioning profile.

Comment: I will give this a try and see it it does the trick.  Thanks!

Comment: Sure, if you still encounter issues, comment here and I'll check back.

Comment: I don't mean to waste your time, but Apple is having trouble with logins for the past couple of days.  I can't even log into my developer account right now.  When I am able to get in, I will try your solution.

Comment: I am not the OP but am having the same problem. After checking and re0checking all of the above points, I still get the "because its use of the com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers entitlement is not allowed" message :(

Comment: For me, the only way around this was to disable iCloud for the app, and remove the iCloud related items from the Entitlements. Not such a big deal for my app, but this solution wouldn't work for everybody

Comment: @coneybeare It certainly won't work for people who want to use iCloud. :)

Comment: @craig Genius! Sorry to take so long to get back to this. I am not using iCloud, but I still have it turned on. The app compiles and the window pops up.  Really appreciate it.

Comment: coneybeare's suggestion did not work for me. Disabled iCloud, regenerated and reinstalled provisioning profile, removed iCloud entitlements. Xcode 4.2.1.