# taskgated: killed app because its use of the com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers entitlement is not allowed

Tags: ios, icloud

So, create a vanilla project, build & run...  App does not appear.  Open console:

"1/10/12 6:32:29.967 PM taskgated: killed com.myapp.TEST[pid 28092] because its use of the com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers entitlement is not allowed"

Pretty much the same question as here
[Turning Entitlements on in Xcode Prevents Bare Bones App From Launching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990353/turning-entitlements-on-in-xcode-prevents-bare-bones-app-from-launching)

And here.
[Mac application crashes (killed due to entitlements) regardless of whether entitlements are enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8757811/mac-application-crashes-killed-due-to-entitlements-regardless-of-whether-entit)

I am not using iCloud.  In fact I haven't even changed the default project.  Any solutions or ideas?  Thanks to anyone who has overcome this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, from the docs even, that the XCode "default provisioning profile" which it automatically creates and updates ALSO includes iCloud permissions.  Since those permissions are app specific, presumably this breaks every app using the default xcode profile.

I'm not sure why this isn't an epidemic, but in my case it meant that instead of using the "XCode wildcard app id", I had to create a new "basic wildcard app id" without iCloud.  Using this and creating a new provisioning profile, adding it, etc, worked.  It means I can't let XCode handle the profiles anymore :(

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this work by going into the provisioning portal, disabling iCloud on my wildcard App ID, going back to Xcode, and refreshing the provisioning profiles list.